# Why does my API request returns empty values on each POST arguments?

Tags: python, api, flask, elm, flask-restful

While on localhost, I have downloaded Flask-Cors. I tried sending few requests to flask server as the code below the entire code is on github.

unfortunately i can't get any data using POST request.

here is my ELM code.

```
module Update exposing (update)
import Http
import Json.Decode exposing (..)

import Types exposing (..)



update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of Username str -> ({ model | loginUserName = str}, Cmd.none)
                Password str -> ({ model | loginPassword = str}, Cmd.none)
                Login -> (model, login model.loginUserName model.loginPassword)
                LoginResult (Ok username) -> ({ model | user = LoggedInUser { userName = username}},
                                              Cmd.none)
                LoginResult (Err _) -> (model, Cmd.none)
                Logout -> (model, Cmd.none)


login : String -> String -> Cmd Msg
login username password =
    let url = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/user/login"
        request = Http.get url decodeLogin
    in Http.send LoginResult request


decodeLogin: Decoder String
decodeLogin = at ["username"] string

-- Or
--decodeLogin : Decoder String
--decodeLogin = decodeString (field "username" string)
```

The rest of the code is at [Github](https://github.com/afidegnum/myelm/tree/master/web)

Here is my Flask endpoint for the API

```
@app.route("/api/user/login/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'Got request for login'
    print args
    print kwargs
    print request.args
    print request.args.get("username")
    print request.values.get("username")
    print request.method
    print request.form['username']

    response = {'username': 'Erik'}

    dict = request.args
    for key in dict:
        print 'form key ' + dict[key]

    return jsonify(response)
```

The rest of this code is also [`at this link`](https://github.com/afidegnum/myelm/blob/master/server.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your server is expecting the body of the POST to be in multiple `key=val` format, rather than in JSON. You can use [`multipartBody`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http#multipartBody) to achieve this:

```elm
import Http exposing (..)

login : String -> String -> Cmd Msg
login username password =
    let url = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/user/login"
        body =
            multipartBody
                [ stringPart "username" username
                , stringPart "password" password
                ]
        request = Http.post url body decodeLogin
    in Http.send LoginResult request
```

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add that though you can direct a request at the ip address `0.0.0.0` this is not the address your flask app is listening on. `0.0.0.0` signifies that the the flask app is listening at all available ip addresses (which does not include `0.0.0.0` because it is reserved for this purpose). Your flask app can be reached on `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`.